# javascript post base64 encrypt and decrypt image

Tags: javascript, php, html, base64

I am working with javascript image post in base64.
When the image is posted it showsinvalid image all the time. How to solve this?

I can't understand what's the problem.

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {
  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {

   var xxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xxhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               
       document.getElementById('output').src = "data:image/png;base64,//" + this.responseText + "";


                        
                                                        
                            }
                     };
                      xxhttp.open("POST", "itemimages.php", true);
                      xxhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                      xxhttp.send('image_data=' + reader.result);
        
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/png" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)" />
<img id="output" src="" alt="" />
```

My php code in "itemimages.php" file

```
$imagedata = $_POST['image_data'];

    $imagepath = "images/aa.png";

    $imagedata = preg_replace( '/data:image\/.*;base64,/', '', $imagedata );
     if(file_put_contents($imagepath,base64_decode($imagedata)))
     {
        echo "$imagedata"; 
     }
```

It contains an encrypted string but the string is not showing an image

Comment: You should probably be using a content type of form data and not form-url encoded.

Comment: I already try with this `    xxhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");` 
but it take blank data.

Comment: Note that you add `data:image/png;base64,//` to the data before sending, but only remove `data:image/png;base64,` in your `preg_replace()` call. This could be resulting in an invalid encoding. Try changing the regular expression to `/data:image\/.*;base64,\/\//` instead and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your data arrives correctly to php ... you should try this

```
$imagedata = $_POST['image_data'];

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $imagedata);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

$imagepath = "images/aa." . $image_type_aux[1];

file_put_contents($imagepath , $image_base64);
```

--- javascript ---

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {
  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log(reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

-- html --

```
<input type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)">
```

Comment: javascript function are same. Your function just output on the console.